# How can I replace some cells of a column by others that depends on a interval

Tags: python, for-loop, intervals

I am working on a medical project. I have a large dataset that I had to clean and transform it. I have a special column (df['code']) that have numbers that corresponds to codes. Now I want to replace all the codes whose quantity is lower than 250 by some other value corresponding to intervals. Part of the code is already done:

```
# Save some codes
threshold_count = 250 
count_diag = Counter(df['code'])
small_codes_itens = [k for k, count in count_diag.items() if count < threshold_count]

# Only codes with less than 250 
small_diagcodes = df['code'][df['code'].isin(small_codes_itens)].str.slice(start=0, stop=3, step=1)
small_diagcodes = small_diagcodes[~small_diagcodes.str.contains("[a-zA-Z]").fillna(False)]
small_diagcodes.fillna(value='1500', inplace=True)
small_diagcodes = small_diagcodes.astype(int)

ranges = [(1, 140), (140, 240), (240, 280), (280, 290), (290, 320), (320, 390), 
               (390, 460), (460, 520), (520, 580), (580, 630), (630, 680), (680, 710),
               (710, 740), (740, 760), (760, 780), (780, 800), (800, 1000), (1000,2000)]
```

So counter_diag is just used to select the codes that appears less than 250 times. I just want to work with those codes. So I save that codes in small_diagcodes. What it is in this variable is like 50, or 192 or 250,... , that are not the quantities but the code itself. So, for example, if 50 is a code that appears less than 250 times, it will be selected. Then, what I want to do is to replace in every row of df['code'] = 50 by 0 because it corresponds to the first range, i. e. (1,140).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

```
t = [r for r in ranges if r[0]<=count_diag and r[1]>count_diag]
result = count_diag
if len(t)>0:
    result = t[0][0]
```

Comment: Hi! counter_diag is just used to select the codes that appears less than 250 times. I just want to work with those codes. So I save that codes in small_diagcodes. What it is in this variable is like 50, or 192 or 250,... , that are not the quantities but the code itself. So, for example, if 50 is a code that appears more than 250 times, it will be selected. Then, what I want to do is to replace in every row of df['code'] =50 by 0 because it corresponds to the first range, i. e. (1,140). I don't know If I was clear.. Did you understand?

Comment: so for every element in df['code'], if this element is also in small_codes_itens, this element should be repleaced?

Comment: Yes, exactly that!